# Is it possible to define a block as a member of a class?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to implement a very simple strategy class in Objective-C that allows for strategies to be defined inline instead of being defined through inheritance. Currently my code looks like this:

```
@interface SSTaskStrategy : NSObject {
    (NSArray *)(^strategy)(void);
}

@end
```

I thought this would work, but I'm getting the error

> Expected specifier-qualifier-list before '(' token

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should drop the parentheses around `NSArray *` in your ivar definition:

```
@interface SSTaskStrategy : NSObject {
    NSArray * (^strategy)(void);
}

@end
```

Also, I highly recommend that you use a `typedef` for more clarity:

```
typedef NSArray * (^Strategy)(void);

@interface SSTaskStrategy : NSObject {
   Strategy block;
}

@end
```

This allows you to reference this block with the name `Strategy` instead of having to use the funky syntax every single time you wish to reference it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface SSTaskStrategy : NSObject {
    NSArray* (^strategy)(void);
}
```

You don't need to put the `(` `)` around the return type.